# How can I use php inside a jquery function?

Tags: php, jquery

With my code I can change my text by click:

```js
$('.SeeMore').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass('SeeMore');
  if($this.hasClass('SeeMore')){
   $this.text('+ more');   
  } else {
   $this.text('- less');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="SeeMore" style="cursor:pointer">+ more</li>
```

This is working well so far. But because I have different language versions of my page I want to exchange the words with php:

```
   <script> 
       $('.SeeMore').click(function(){

        var more = <?php echo $lang['MORE']; ?>
        var less = <?php echo $lang['LESS']; ?>
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('SeeMore');
        if($this.hasClass('SeeMore')){
            $this.text(more);           
        } else {
            $this.text(less);
        }
    });</script>
```

Unfortunately now my code is not working anymore and I do not know why.

Comment: You need to use `"`, Ex: `var more = "<?php echo $lang['MORE']; ?>"`

Comment: try echoing the whole <script>

Comment: @deviantxdes, The OP needs to use PHP inside jQuery...

Comment: @FrayneKonok Thank you, this is working very well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that is missed by you-

```
 1. Semi-colon at the end of the statement.
 2. Double / single quotation around the PHP statement inside the jQuery.
```

You need to use `"`, **Ex:** `var more = "<?php echo $lang['MORE']; ?>";`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the semicolons and quotes:

```
var more = "<?php echo $lang['MORE']; ?>";
var less = "<?php echo $lang['LESS']; ?>";
```

writing code-generating-code is hard and can be confusing. Better use a decent template system (e.g. Smarty).

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting the quotes:

```
var more = "<?php echo $lang['MORE']; ?>";
var less = "<?php echo $lang['LESS']; ?>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use data attributes

html:

```
<li class="SeeMore" data-less="<?php echo $lang['LESS']; ?>" data-more="<?php echo $lang['MORE']; ?>" style="cursor:pointer">+ more</li>
```

js:

```
   $('.SeeMore').click(function(){

        var more = $(this).attr('data-more');
        var less = $(this).attr('data-less');
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('SeeMore');
        if($this.hasClass('SeeMore')){
            $this.text(more);           
        } else {
            $this.text(less);
        }
    });
```

PS: don't forget to wrap you click event in a document ready statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use your php variables inside jquery with the following code:

```js
token = "<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
var more = <?php echo json_encode($mymore); ?>;
```